# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ADDRESS' to 'API.Models.ADDRESS'?

Tags: entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api

I recently updated Visual Studio from Update 2 to Update 4 and now I can't seem to assign my queries to model classes.

example:

```
ADDRESS get_address = db.ADDRESS.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.[ADDRESS] where ObjectID = " + id).First();
```

Returns the error in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed my model by updating model from database and refreshing the tables. The building the project resolved the errors.